# Automatically discover topics when using topics.regex configuration for Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi, s3-kafka-connector

When I'm using `topics.regex` config option for Kafka Connector Sink (in this particular case Confluent S3 Sink) everything works as expected when sink is first started (it discovers all topics and start consuming messages from them). I want to be able to also create some topics later. I can't find anywhere in documentation what is expected behaviour here, but I wanted to be able to somehow automatically start consuming new topics with name matching provided regex. Is it possible at all? If not what would be best way to implement some automation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to do anything. It will find the new topic automatically if it matches the regex. But it is not immediate - it might take a few minutes (I think it is driven by the metadata refresh which is by default 5 minutes?). I never used it directly with the S3 connector you mention. But it worked fine for me with other connectors and I think there should be no differences.

Comment: Thanks, will check that. I need to be more patient I suppose.